# I want to get the number of elements in the array while using sizeof() functions in c it returns unexpected values

Tags: c, sizeof

I have already tried using sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])
this returns value 0.

I have also tried sizeof(a)/sizeof(Employee)
this also have same issue

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Employee_Details
{
    long int Emp_id;
    char Emp_name[200];
    char Emp_city[200];
} Employee;

int main()
{
    Employee *a = (Employee *) malloc(10 * sizeof(Employee));
    int n = sizeof(a);// this should return size of array a =10
                      // but it returns 4
    printf("%d", n);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a` is a pointer, not array. There's no way to find the number of elements, you have to store it separately.

Comment: The `sizeof` operator (it isn't a function) would report the number of bytes in the object.  Even if `a` was an array of 10 `Employee` structures, the size reported would probably 4040 or 4080 bytes  — it would categorically not be `10`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sir, but when I try to use sizeof operator on a to get the number of bytes it gives 4 instead of 4040.

Comment: Yes, it would.  That is, on a 32-bit machine, `sizeof(a)` is bound to return `4` because `a` is a pointer.  Note that I said "_IF_ `a` was an array of 10 `Employee` structures", but it isn't.  It's a pointer, and on your 32-bit machine, a pointer is 4 bytes long.  So the size of `a` will be 4 (on a 332-bit machine; 8 on a 64-bit machine).  C does not record the sizes of allocations made by `malloc()` where you can access it; you must track the size allocated yourself.  And, as I said (or at least intimated), `sizeof` returns a byte count — not the number of elements (except for 'byte' types).